# How to vectorize this mathematical formula?

Tags: r, math, matrix, vectorization

I'm evaluating [this formula](https://www.overleaf.com/read/djwtkxhywdxs) (from [Székely and Rizzo, 2013](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375813000633), page 1263), in which `a` and `b` are symmetric, `n`-by-`n` matrices.

How can I vectorize the section with the nested `for` loop? I feel like there are probably clever matrix manipulation tricks that I could use here, maybe along with the `sweep` function.

Here is what I have now:

```
u_squared <- function(a, b, n) {
  a. <- .colSums(a, n, n)
  b. <- .colSums(b, n, n)
  a.. <- sum(a.)
  b.. <- sum(b.)
  u1 <- 0
  u2 <- 0
  u3 <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      u1 <- u1 + a[i, j] * b[i, j]
      u2 <- u2 + a[i, j] * (b.. - 2*b.[j] - 2*b.[i] + 2*b[i, j])
      u3 <- u3 + a[i, j] * (b.[i] - b[i, j])
    }
  }
  u1 <- u1 / (n * (n-1))
  u2 <- u2 / (n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3))
  u3 <- u3 / (n * (n-1) * (n-2))
  return (u1 + u2 - 2 * u3)
}
```

For instance, I know that `u1` could be computed simply as `u1 <- a * b` but I wanted to unroll the entire formula just to demonstrate the underlying math. What I'm looking for are similar vectorizations for `u2` and `u3`.

Comment: Not everybody has an access to your formula behind paywall.

Comment: @ExperimenteR that's why I wrote it as clearly and pedantically as possible in a `for` loop. I'd have written it out with MathJax but we don't have it on this site.

Comment: Googled for open access. Same authors has a r package named `energy`.

Comment: @ExperimenteR I'm well aware. I also didn't find an open access version of this particular paper. Would you mind sharing the link so I can add it to my post?

Comment: @ExperimenteR I added a link to an Overleaf document with the formula as it appears in the paper

Comment: From your linked document, `a_{.j}` seems to be`rowMeans` whereas your code suggests quite a different thing. Forgive me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @Khashaa the matrices are symmetric, so the row and column means are the same

Comment: Ahh, I see. Also, maybe a minor point. $\sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij}$ is `colSums`.

Comment: @Khashaa good catch! They had used similar notation for means earlier in the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be easily vectorized

```
u_squared1 <- function(a, b, n){
  b. <- matrix(.colSums(b, n, n), n, n) 
  B1 <- b.. - 2 * b. - 2 * t(b.) + 2*b
  B2 <- b. - b
  u1 <- sum(a*b) / (n * (n-1))
  u2 <- sum(a*B1) / (n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3))
  u3 <- sum(a*B2) / (n * (n-1) * (n-2))
  return (u1 + u2 - 2 * u3)
}
```

Comment: Could I just do `b. <- matrix(.colSums(b, n, n), n, n)` and then `B1 <- mean(b.) - 2 * b. - 2 * t(b.) + 2*b`?

Comment: Also note that I edited the OP after you pointed out I'd written "means" when I meant "sums"

Comment: @ssdecontrol I approved your edit, but you need to define `b.. <-  mean(b.)` in the scope of the function.

Comment: of course. I didn't even see that you had wrapped it in a function, it just caught my eye. Either way, it works. I need to learn to get more comfortable with argument recycling